# Subprocess termination in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a Python script which starts a subprocess another Python script using subprocess.Popen(). This subprocess starts another subprocess( another Python script) using Popen. 
Script A calls script B which calls script C.
If I kill process script B using os.kill() will it terminate the process running script C.
If not is there any way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands, if script `A` kills `B` using `os.kill` then `C` will not itself be killed.

In order to ensure this, script `B` could take care of killing `C` when it exits

```
# this is in script B
import functools, atexit

def kill_children(*pids):
    import os, signal

    for pid in pids or []:
        os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)

# we start a process for C
c_pid = ...

# kill C when we we exit
atexit.register(functools.partial(kill_children, c_pid))
```

Comment: Maybe it would be an idea to use `os.killpg` here, as it would kill all the children.